# Decoding multi level json in php

Tags: php, json, curl

Im trying to access the different results in the following response but can't seem to get it to work:

```
{
  "id": "REGNOHERE",
  "registration": "REGNOHERE",
  "vehicle": {
    "dvla": {
      "make": "AUDI",
      "model": "A4 SE TDI 6SP",
      "regDate": "2008-09-29",
      "v5cDate": "2011-10-27",
      "vin": "WAUZZZ8K99A099266",
      "colour": "BLUE",
      "source": "UK",
      "exported": "1",
      "exportedDate": "2015-12-09",
      "imported": null,
      "importedNi": null,
      "importedDate": null,
      "body": "4 DOOR SALOON",
      "bodyClass": "CAR",
      "seatingCapacity": 5,
      "wheelplan": "2 AXLE RIGID BODY",
      "co2": 139,
      "cc": 1968,
      "engineNumber": "CAG 120938",
      "engineCode": "2.0 TDI E4",
      "fuel": "HEAVY OIL",
      "maxPower": 105,
      "maxTechMass": 2010
    }
```

i used the following to decode the response, and tried to acces the data within it

```
$data = json_decode($response, TRUE);
$carmake['vehicle']['dvla']['make'];
```

am i missing something??

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$data` not `$carmake`? I'm assuming that the missing 2 `}` is unintentional paste error.

Answer (score 1):

`$carmake` doesn't exist. Your array created from `json_decode` is `$data`.  To assign `$carmake`, you can go about it this way:

```
$carmake = $data['vehicle']['dvla']['make'];
echo $carmake;
// output..
// AUDI
```

Comment: brilliant thanks! i knew i'd missed something simple!